# Do insertions take longer as the number of rows in a table increase? Why?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

If I have a table with a primary key, i.e. a physically arranged, clustered index that is of type integer and has an identity value like so (pseudo-SQL-code):

```
MyTable
--------
Id ( int, primary key, identity(1, 1) )
MyField1
MyField2
```

1. Would an insert operation in this table take more time as the number of rows in the table grew? Why?

   The only reason I can imagine it taking longer is if the table rows are stored as nodes of a linked list internally before being flushed to the disk.

   I am assuming that giving a clustered index to a table makes a copy of the table data and stores that as an array, so traversing that array is a lot faster (constant time as you need only one `JMP` instruction by a single integer (or machine bit-ness, i.e. 32 bits on a 32-bit machine and 64 bits on a 64-bit machine) size) than traversing the linked list.
2. And would it make any difference to the differential insertion time if the table did not have an index? That is, if the primary key in the above case was missing?

Where may I read about how a relational database stores a table in the RAM and on the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the overhead for inserting a row consists of a few components.  Off-hand, I can think of:

1. Finding a page to put the row.
2. Updating indexes.
3. Logging the transaction.
4. Any overhead for triggers and constraints.

For (1).  Because of the clustered index on an identity column, a new row goes into the table at the "end" of the table -- meaning on the last page.  There is not a relationship between the size of the table and finding space for the row, in this case.

For (2).  There is a very small additional overhead for updating the clustered index as the table grows.  But this is very small -- and fragmentation doesn't seem to be an issue.

For (3).  This is not related to the table size.

For (4).  You don't seem to have triggers or constraints, so this isn't an issue.

So, by my reckoning, there would be very little additional overhead for an insert as the table grows bigger.

Note:  There may be other factors as well.  For instance, you might need to grow the table space to support a larger table.  However, that isn't really related just to the size of the table, just to the relationship between the size of data and the available resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. This was very helpful. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the circumstances in which #1 and #2 would adversely affect the insertion time? Also, where may I read about this stuff?